# Check if the child of a game object is the same as other game object's child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

SO i am making a Slots game but the method i check for winning combinations doesnt work and im not sure what to try.

I managed to make the symbols show by creating them as a child under the reel game object using an
ienumerator

```
IEnumerator SpinReel(int reelIndex)
{
   
    // spin for a random amount of time
    float spinTime = Random.Range(1.5f, 3.0f);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spinTime);
    
    
    // choose a random symbol
    int symbolIndex = Random.Range(0, 5);
    GameObject symbol;
    switch (symbolIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            symbol = cherryPrefab;
            break;
        case 1:
            symbol = grapePrefab;
            break;
        case 2:
            symbol = sevenPrefab;
            break;
        case 3:
            symbol = orangePrefab;
            break;
        case 4:
            symbol = lemonPrefab;
            break;
        default:
            symbol = cherryPrefab;
            break;
        }

    
    //instantiate symbol on reel
    GameObject newSymbol = Instantiate(symbol, reels[reelIndex].transform);
    newSymbol.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    // wait for another 1.5 seconds before starting to spin the 2nd reel
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
```

This is my current methid for checking combinations but it does not want to work:

```
void Check()
{
    if (reels[2].transform.GetChild(0) == reels[1].transform.GetChild(0) &&
    reels[1].transform.GetChild(1) == reels[0].transform.GetChild(0))        
    {
        Debug.Log("yee");
        currency += bet * 2;
        Debug.Log(currency);
    }
    else  if (reels[2].transform.GetChild(0) == reels[1].transform.GetChild(0) ||
    reels[1].transform.GetChild(1) == reels[0].transform.GetChild(0))        
    {
        Debug.Log("yee");
        // player wins, add winnings to currency
        currency += bet;
        Debug.Log(currency);
    }
}
```

any idea of why it wont work or other ways i could try?

written in C# unity

Comment: If you're comparing different GameObjects to each other, they will never be the same - that's because objects are compared by reference, and two instances of the same prefab will have different references. There are a few ways to approach this - you could add a tag to each prefab and compare those instead, or you could have a data structure behind the scenes that tracks the game state (like an array of the symbols chosen). A backing data structure would be preferable, since then you can separate your game logic from the visual representation (the GameObjects) that the player is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little unclear to me. Could you show the output that you get from running it ?

Also I understand that you have 3 reels, but if I'm not mistaken you should only instantiate one symbol from each of them, so inside your Check function why do you compare the second child of reels[1] with the first child of reels[0]

Also the tansform.getChild method returns the transform component of the child objects, shouldn't you be comparing the symbols instead ? For instance by getting the GameObjects and comparing the symbol attribute (if you have one)

Doing so, your Check method would look like this :

```
void Check()
{
    if (reels[2].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.symbol == reels[1].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.symbol &&
    reels[1].transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.symbol == reels[0].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.symbol)        
    {
        Debug.Log("yee");
        currency += bet * 2;
        Debug.Log(currency);
    }
    else  if (reels[2].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.symbol == reels[1].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.symbol ||
    reels[1].transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.symbol == reels[0].transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.symbol)        
    {
        Debug.Log("yee");
        // player wins, add winnings to currency
        currency += bet;
        Debug.Log(currency);
    }
}
```

Finally if this does not solve your problem could you show how you call the SpinReel function ? When you call WaitForSeconds(1.5f) at the end I don't see how that waits for the next reel to begin spinning.